# Actual (Real) Dimensions of objects when printed

Tags: inkscape

I'm VERY new to InkScape and am under pressure to learn it fast for a project in the making. I will be using the printed output as a cutting template for an ABS project box, so dimensions are critical.

How is an object's size measured? In specific, I have a 45mm x 26mm cutout to define using a rectangle. The rectangle is sized as mentioned with an outline stroke of .5mm (though when printed it looks more like 1 mm, but ...).

My question is: How is the object ACTUALLY sized: outside to outside of stroke lines, inside to inside of stroke lines, or center of one stroke line to the other.

I guess what I'm asking is: do the rectangle stroke lines define the outside (full) dimensions of the printed object OR is the actual object inside the stroke lines? Thanks, in advance for any help.

Comment: It may be time for you to try numeric input methods.

Answer (score 2):

By default, stroke widths, filters like blurs, markers and a few other things are included in the bounding box, thus in the width and height input boxes in the toolbar.

If you don't like that, you can set the 'Bounding box to use' setting in the preferences under the 'Tools' section (click on 'Tools' directly instead of expanding the section) to 'Geometric' instead of 'Visual'.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the view.

Select a simple rectangle outline with a very thick border (20) which fits nicely into the screen and zoom the screen to fit the object, so that it is easy to read the rulers. Some views show middle of the stroke, some views ("modify") show the bounding rectangle.

Comment: Or just draw a rectangle without stroke and use that as reference?

Comment: I don't have experience with ABS, but if it is a cutting tool, you usually have a width of the cut and need to know, how wide the cut is. So the outline is the path, where your cutting tool, laser or some rotating metal head, drives along.

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I mean is to use a rectangle without stroke with known dimensions and center it on top of the rectangle with stroke to check where the stroke aligns to. Seems easier than counting ticks on the ruler.