# Inkscape stroke width and SVG position?

Tags: inkscape, svg

In my svg, I've made sure I have no `transform` on any nodes on the way to my rect:

```svg
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <g
       id="my_group">
    ...
      <rect
         style="display:inline;fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.5;stop-color:#000000"
         id="my_rect"
         width="40"
         height="13"
         x="0"
         y="0"
         ry="1.5" />
    ...
```

... and yet, when I open this in Inkscape 1.2 and select the rect, I get this shown:

[image: Inkscape]

That is, for a rect with `x="0" y="0" width="40" height="13" style="...stroke-width:0.5;..." ...` in SVG, I get "X=-0.250 Y=-0.250 W: 40.500 H: 13.500" shown as info in Ikscape when I click on the same rect.

Is this a standard/unchanging behavior of Inkscape: that whatever the settings in the SVG, ultimately Inkscape will show (svg width + stroke width) for W, (svg height + stroke width) for H, (svg x - stroke width/2) for X and (svg y - stroke width/2) for Y - at least for objects that can be stroked, like rect? ( I guess, in this case, svg x,y define the upper left corner of the rect including the stroke; Inkscape X,Y is the upper left corner of the "virtual rectangle" which then gets stroked afterwards (half stroke width outside, half stroke width inside )

Or is it controllable by some switch in Inkscape?

Comment: Check out one of my older answers [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/155419/165916). Basically, set 'Bounding box to use' to 'Geometric' in the preferences to make Inkscape ignore things like stroke-width.

Comment: Thanks @Xrott - that explains it